# Draw image on a jpanel from a bytestream

Tags: java, image, paintcomponent, pixel

If I have an image in a string-vector as hexvalues - and want to reproduce the image in a JPanel - how would a loop look like in the overriden method paintComponent(Graphics g) ? I guess a nested loop should be suitable to draw row by row downwards the panel. But how could I possibly know how many bytes each row are? Is the answer just the dimensions of the image? For instance - if the image has the dimensions 1000 * 910 - I shold iterate 1000 times in x direction and 910 times in y-direction? BUt it completely fails - as you can see in the images:

the image
format .jpg

dimensions: 100 * 910

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {

        for (int y = 0; y < 910; y++) {
            int red = Integer.parseInt(bytesInHex[y], 16);
            int green = Integer.parseInt(bytesInHex[y + 1], 16);
            int blue = Integer.parseInt(bytesInHex[y + 2], 16);
            g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
        }
    }

}
```

I know the code may be wrong - but its better to show my bad try than to show nothing at all. I give a snippet below of the stream (hex converted to int)

[image]

According to the image - I think 3 successive values occupy one pixel on the screen. Theres no transparency so we have red, green, blue. I simply put 3 succisive bytes (ints) in the g.setcolor(new Color(r, g, b)), and then draw a line (dot).

Obviously something is completely wrong here - what I see when running this app is just stripes in white and black.

[image]

So - obviously my approach is completely wrong - Can anyone come with som tips and hints, and maybe tell me whats wrong?

thanks

Comment: How (and why) is the image converted to hex? Are you sure the conversion is valid?

Comment: @copeg - its because the inputstream is a bytestream and bytes in java are signed - ranging from -128 to 127. Therefore - values must be converted to hex, and then back to int

Comment: Not sure I follow the context completely, but...`1000 * 910 - I shold iterate 1000 times in x direction and 910 times in y-direction?` try looping over the 1D array by indexes of 3, for example `bytesInHex[3*(1000 * y + x)]`. Also consider first drawing to a Bufferedimage (outside of paintComponent), then render the image using `g.drawImage`

Comment: If the input is a byte stream, can't you just run it through ImageIO.read? Assuming that the data represents an image format and not just the pixel data

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the orientation of your data, but assuming its raw colour data x then y, you need to iterate and reference appropriately:

```
for (int y=0; y<height; y++) {
  for (int x=0; x<width; x+=3) {
    int pixelIndex = y*width + x;
    Color col = new Color(Integer.parseInt(bytesInHex[pixelIndex], 16)
                          Integer.parseInt(bytesInHex[pixelIndex + 1], 16), 
                          Integer.parseInt(bytesInHex[pixelIndex + 2], 16));
    //draw pixel
  }
}
```